# Does in plane exist $22$ points and $22$ such circles that each circle contains at least $7$ points and each point is on at least $7$ circles.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, contest-math, algebraic-combinatorics

> *Does in plane exist $22$ points and $22$ such circles that each circle contains at least $7$ points and each point is on at least $7$ circles.*

---

I have solved this one but now I can't remember how I did it. I just remember that I used some linear algebra and double counting.

Suppose each point $P_i\in \{P_1,P_2,...P_{22}\}$ is on $p_i\geq 7$ circles among circles $C_1,C_2,...,C_{22}$. Since each pair $\{C_i,C_j\}$ share at most $2$ points and each point is on $\displaystyle{p_i\choose 2}$ pair of circles, we have:

$$ 2\cdot {22\choose 2} \geq \sum _{i=1}^{22} {p_i\choose 2} \geq 22 {7\choose 2} $$
Since we must have all equalities we deduce that $p_i = 7$ for all $i$ and each pair of circles intersect in exactly two points. Now since $$ 22\cdot 7 \leq \sum _{i=1}^{22} |C_i| =  \sum _{i=1}^{22}p_i = 22\cdot 7$$
so each circle contains exactly $7$ points.

Comment: Your use of "each point is **on** each circle implies that the points line on the circle, not inside it.  When you say "each circle contains at least 7 points" do you mean the points lie **on** the circle rather than inside the circle?

Comment: @user247327:  a circle is the perimeter.  If the interior were wanted, the term should be a disk.

Comment: As there are $21$ pairs of points on each circle, each pair of circles must intersect in two points.  Similarly each pair of points must be on one circle.  This is sounding like a projective plane to me.

Comment: Your solution shows that, if there is such a configuration, then each of its circles must contain exactly $7$ points and each of its points must lie on exactly $7$ circles. I am not quite sure if I would consider this as actually showing that such a configuration does exist.

Comment: Ok guys, I remember the solution now. You have to make an incidence matrix $A$ and show that the determinant of $M = A\cdot A^T$ is not a square (which should be) and thus such a configuration does not exist. Funny, no one like this problem though.

Comment: I like it. You can write an answer yourself, this is acceptable and even encouraged.

Answer (score 8):

As we already see in the introduction each point is on $7$ circles and each circle contains $7$ points. Also every two circles meet at $2$ points.

Let $A$ be an incident matrix, so $a_{ij} = 1$ if $P_j \in C_i$, else $a_{ij} =0$. Let $M:= A\cdot A^T$, then determinant of
$M$ is a perfect square: $\det (M) =\det (A\cdot A^T)
=\det A \cdot \det A^T =(\det A)^2$. But $$ M=
\begin{bmatrix}
  7 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 & 2 \\
  2 & 7 & 2 & \cdots & 2 & 2 \\
  2 & 2 & 7 & \cdots & 2 & 2 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots& 7 & 2 \\
  2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 & 7 \\
\end{bmatrix} \sim
\begin{bmatrix}
  5 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -5 \\
  0 & 5 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -5 \\
  0 & 0 & 5 & \cdots & 0 & -5 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots& 5 & -5 \\
  2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 & 7 \\
\end{bmatrix} \sim
\begin{bmatrix}
  5 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 5 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 5 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots& 5 & 0 \\
  2 & 2 & 2 & \cdots & 2 & 49 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $\det (M)= 5^{21}\cdot 49$ which is not a perfect square. Thus such a configuration does not exist.

Comment: What is the geometric meaning of the determinant of $A$?